# What is the implementation of GetOwnPropertyNames() in javascript

Tags: javascript

While studying getOwnPropetyNames() function Mozilla MDN [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

I came across this example

```
// non-enumerable property
var my_obj = Object.create({}, {
  getFoo: {
    value: function() { return this.foo; },
    enumerable: false
  }
});
my_obj.foo = 1;

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(my_obj).sort()); 
// logs ["foo", "getFoo"]
```

I understand that the function getOwnPropertyNames returns array of name of all the enumerable and nonEnumerable  property.

I want to know in the above example
What is the context of using following function and what case do we use it in.

```
getFoo: {
        value: function() { return this.foo; },
        enumerable: false
      }
```

I know might be silly question , I am trying to learn JS in depth so hope you all don't mind answering .

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You've asked what the *implementation* of `getOwnPropertyNames` is (which [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.getownpropertynames) can tell you), but in the text of the question you seem instead to be asking what you would use it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "when/why would you use `getOwnPropertyNames`", the answer is "Any time you want to get all the object's own property names, even the non-enumerable ones." But that sort of begs the question.

So: Suppose you were writing a console like the one in browsers. When the user logs an object, they probably want to see not just all of the enumerable properties of the object, but also the *non-enumerable* ones like your `getFoo`. So you'd use `getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `Object.keys` or a `for-in` loop, because it will include non-enumerable properties. (In ES2015 [aka ES6] and later, you'd probably *also* use `getOwnPropertySymbols` so you could show properties named with `Symbol`s rather than strings.)